# Is the following differential operator closed (closabe)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

Let $L$ be the following differential operator.

$L: C^2(\Bbb{R}^2_+)\to C^0(\Bbb{R}^2_+) $

$$Lf = \partial_x f(x,y) (y-x) + \partial_y f (x,y)(x-y) + \frac{1}{2} \bigg( \partial_{xx} f(x,y)x + \partial_{yy} f(x,y)y\bigg)$$

I would like to know if this operator is closed, that is, if $f_n \to f$ and $L f_n\to g$ then $f \in D(L)$ and $Lf = g$.

I believe this is true, since for simpler operator $D: C^2([a,b])\to C^0([a,b]):  $$\Delta f = f''$ we get that $f_n \to f$ and $f_n''\to g$ implies that $f \in C^2$ and that $f'' = g$.

Here the norm is the sup norm and $C^0(\Bbb{R}^2_+)$ is the set of continuous functions that vanish at infinity.

Is there any approach to this kind of problem?

Comment: I don't see why you should end up in a space of functions vanishing at infinity at all? Maybe I'm confused...

Comment: @mickep that is not clear to me neither. It seems that the space of functions vanishing at infinity is a goos space to characterize stochastic processes, see Liggett Continuous time Markov chains pag 97

Comment: I see, and it is explained in section 3.1 why they do this. I'm not familiar with this point of view, but I wonder if the domain of your $L$ should be $L$ in $C^2$ such that $Lf\in C^0$. If you are not studying Markov processes, but rather differential operators in general, I suggest that you look at your operator as an unbounded operator in the Hilbert space $L^2$ instead. There is a lot of literature on that point of view. Weidmann, for example, has written well on the subject.

Comment: @mickep As a matter of fact, I am sudying Makov process. Thank you for the reference, I will look it up.